# Поворот фигуры вокруг заданной точки на угол

Tags: java

Рисую овал следующим образом g.fillOval(0, 0, 100, 40); 
Как повернуть его относительно центра фигуры на произвольный угол?

Comment: Каким графическим фреймворком пользуетесь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate(double)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void rotate(double theta, double anchorx, double anchory)
```

идеально подходит.